# How to convert JSON stirng with multiple key values to JSON object in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

This is my JSON data:

```
{  
   "alldata":[  
      {  
         "college1":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1",
                  "name":"nithin",
                  "location":"alkd",
                  "time":"2016-06-24 12:02:28"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"2",
                  "name":"xxx",
                  "location":"sdsdvxc",
                  "time":"2016-06-21 12:49:38"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"3",
                  "name":"xcxc",
                  "location":"xzxzx",
                  "time":"2016-06-21 12:59:49"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"4",
                  "name":"ZA",
                  "location":"BU",
                  "time":"2016-06-23 13:04:25"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"5",
                  "name":"df",
                  "location":"ok",
                  "time":"2016-06-20{"                  id":"12",
                  "name":"vbnb",
                  "location":"sf",
                  "time":"2016-06-23 11:08:47"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"13",
                  "name":"az",
                  "location":"vgfjghgbhjj",
                  "time":"2016-06-24 12:13:44"
               }
            ],
            "last_date":"2016-06-24 12:13:44"
         }
      },
      {  
         "product1":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1",
                  "productname":"soapq",
                  "quantity":"2",
                  "time":"2016-06-23 13:12:27"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"2",
                  "productname":"VCVC",
                  "quantity":"3",
                  "time":"2016-06-23 13:12:13"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"3",
                  "productname":"fym",
                  "quantity":"3",
                  "time":"2016-06-23 13:12:53"
               }
            ],
            "last_date":"2016-06-23 13:12:53"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get these data in to arraylist in Android.

Comment: JSON is not well formatted please update it.

Comment: First try your self, do some googling. thanks in advance

Comment: This JSON response is not formatted. you can check it using any online JSON formatter.

Comment: arraylist class variables ??

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is not valid, i done with corrections as needed for valid JSON data. **Check Valid JSON data as follows :**

```
{
    "alldata": [{
        "college1": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "nithin",
                "location": "alkd",
                "time": "2016-06-24 12:02:28"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "xxx",
                "location": "sdsdvxc",
                "time": "2016-06-21 12:49:38"
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "xcxc",
                "location": "xzxzx",
                "time": "2016-06-21 12:59:49"
            }, {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "ZA",
                "location": "BU",
                "time": "2016-06-23 13:04:25"
            }, {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "df",
                "location": "ok",
                "time": "2016-06-20"
            }, {
                "id": "12",
                "name": "vbnb",
                "location": "sf",
                "time": "2016-06-23 11:08:47"
            }, {
                "id": "13",
                "name": "az",
                "location": "vgfjghgbhjj",
                "time": "2016-06-24 12:13:44"
            }],
            "last_date": "2016-06-24 12:13:44"
        }
    }, {
        "product1": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "productname": "soapq",
                "quantity": "2",
                "time": "2016-06-23 13:12:27"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "productname": "VCVC",
                "quantity": "3",
                "time": "2016-06-23 13:12:13"
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "productname": "fym",
                "quantity": "3",
                "time": "2016-06-23 13:12:53"
            }],
            "last_date": "2016-06-23 13:12:53"
        }
    }]
}
```

then try this tutorial - 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Answer (score 0):

Dear for now youe `JSON` response in not well formatted so its unable to parse it.
But once you correct it than you can parse array using Google `GSON` library. 
Include Google `GSON` library in your project using: `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'`

Than you can parse your `JSON` response as.

```
JSONObject objdataList = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray jsonDataList = objDataList.getJSONArray("alldata");
ArrayList<AllData> records = new Gson().fromJson(jsonDataList.toString(), new TypeToken<List<AllData>>(){}.getType());
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

firstly,the json you give have error.From the json,we can use gson to parse json ,do look like this

> ```
>     Gson gson = new Gson();
>     Person person = gson.fromJson(responseString.toString(),Person.class);
>     List<Person.AlldataBean> list = new ArrayList<Person.AlldataBean>();
>     list.addAll(person.getAlldata());
> ```

After doing this ,you can get the list object,then you can get data from the
list object.

The Person Class is here

> public class Person {

```
/**
 * college1 : {"data":[{"id":"1","name":"nithin","location":"alkd","time":"2016-06-24 12:02:28"},{"id":"2","name":"xxx","location":"sdsdvxc","time":"2016-06-21 12:49:38"},{"id":"3","name":"xcxc","location":"xzxzx","time":"2016-06-21 12:59:49"},{"id":"4","name":"ZA","location":"BU","time":"2016-06-23 13:04:25"},{"id":"5","name":"df","location":"ok","time":"2016-06-20"},{"id":"12","name":"vbnb","location":"sf","time":"2016-06-2311: 08: 47"},{"id":"13","name":"az","location":"vgfjghgbhjj","time":"2016-06-2412: 13: 44"}],"last_date":"2016-06-2412: 13: 44"}
 */

private List<AlldataBean> alldata;

public List<AlldataBean> getAlldata() {
    return alldata;
}

public void setAlldata(List<AlldataBean> alldata) {
    this.alldata = alldata;
}

public static class AlldataBean {
    /**
     * data : [{"id":"1","name":"nithin","location":"alkd","time":"2016-06-24 12:02:28"},{"id":"2","name":"xxx","location":"sdsdvxc","time":"2016-06-21 12:49:38"},{"id":"3","name":"xcxc","location":"xzxzx","time":"2016-06-21 12:59:49"},{"id":"4","name":"ZA","location":"BU","time":"2016-06-23 13:04:25"},{"id":"5","name":"df","location":"ok","time":"2016-06-20"},{"id":"12","name":"vbnb","location":"sf","time":"2016-06-2311: 08: 47"},{"id":"13","name":"az","location":"vgfjghgbhjj","time":"2016-06-2412: 13: 44"}]
     * last_date : 2016-06-2412: 13: 44
     */

    private College1Bean college1;

    public College1Bean getCollege1() {
        return college1;
    }

    public void setCollege1(College1Bean college1) {
        this.college1 = college1;
    }

    public static class College1Bean {
        private String last_date;
        /**
         * id : 1
         * name : nithin
         * location : alkd
         * time : 2016-06-24 12:02:28
         */

        private List<DataBean> data;

        public String getLast_date() {
            return last_date;
        }

        public void setLast_date(String last_date) {
            this.last_date = last_date;
        }

        public List<DataBean> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public static class DataBean {
            private String id;
            private String name;
            private String location;
            private String time;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getLocation() {
                return location;
            }

            public void setLocation(String location) {
                this.location = location;
            }

            public String getTime() {
                return time;
            }

            public void setTime(String time) {
                this.time = time;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}